# Load text file function creates a duplicate - C++

Tags: c++, file-io

im trying to take input from a text file but there is a duplicate on the very end when i load it in.

**

- *Here is what the text file contains:*

**

```
Weapon Name: Katana.
Damage: 20.
Weight: 6.

Weapon Name: Longsword.
Damage: 17.
Weight: 9.

Weapon Name: WarAxe.
Damage: 22.
Weight: 20.

Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 9.
Weight: 6.
```

**

- *Here is what is loaded in:*

**

```
Weapon Name: Katana.
Damage: 20.
Weight: 6.
Weapon Name: Longsword.
Damage: 17.
Weight: 9.
Weapon Name: WarAxe.
Damage: 22.
Weight: 20.
Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 9.
Weight: 6.
Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 9.
Weight: 6.
```

The following function takes in text from the file and adds it to a DoublyLinkedList class i have written.
Here is the function:

```
void Weapons :: getWeapon()
    {
    string fileName = "Weapons\\Weapons.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    string weapon;
    int damage;
    int weight;
    while(infile.good())
    {
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>weapon;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>damage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>weight;
        infile>>garbage;
        cout << weapon << "\n" << damage << "\n" << weight << "\n";
        Weapons w1 (weapon,damage,weight);
        weaponsList.Append(w1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yet another `while (file.eof())` bug. Do it the right way

```
while(infile >> garbage >> garbage >> weapon >> garbage >> 
      damage >> garbage >> garbage >> weight >> garbage)
{
     cout << weapon << "\n" << damage << "\n" << weight << "\n";
     Weapons w1 (weapon,damage,weight);
     weaponsList.Append(w1);
}
```

`eof()` doesn't do what you think it does. How many times does this have to be posted?

Comment: Really... Ive seen it on so many websites :S. Am i using that while with a cout inside to print the file?? I took the while loop you posted and used it in my code and it skips every second weapon...

Comment: Yes, this one is fun http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Files/End.htm Gives completely incorrect description of eof, then admits that it doesn't always work like that, without even acknowledging that they might be talking out their arse. Apparently it's because eof is 'persnickety'!

Comment: @Becca that's because you should remove the `file >>` from inside your loop, you only have it in the `while (...)`

Comment: Brillaint got that working :)  Why would people post incorrect code because they just look like idiots.  Thanks for letting me know because ive been doing a lot of file i/o like that...

Comment: @Becca I guess it's because the way you (and many others) use eof feels natural so they suppose it must be right. So in way I suppose it's the fault of the library designers for giving `eof` a confusing name. `eof` should really be called `last_error_was_caused_by_eof`. Then at least no-one would use it.